# Replace square bracket with new line in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-5.1

I have text per below (from an api response).

```
$a = '[
  {
    "Id": "65486432",
    "RecordType": 20
  },
  {
    "Id": "d1b2abe9",
    "RecordType": 20,
    "ModelsSnapshots": []
  }
]
[
  {
    "Id": "65486432",
    "RecordType": 20
  },
  {
    "Id": "d1b2abe9",
    "RecordType": 20,
    "ModelsSnapshots": []
  }
]'
```

I need to replace the square brackets in the middle with ","

```
]
[
```

So the final output should be like. Note there are also "[]" in the text that I don't want to change.

```
'[
  {
    "Id": "65486432",
    "RecordType": 20
  },
  {
    "Id": "d1b2abe9",
    "RecordType": 20,
    "ModelsSnapshots": []
  }
,
  {
    "Id": "65486432",
    "RecordType": 20
  },
  {
    "Id": "d1b2abe9",
    "RecordType": 20,
    "ModelsSnapshots": []
  }
]'
```

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
$a -replace "\]`n\[", ","
```

This works in this example, but not in the actual file, so other alternative solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your file may contain CR&LF instead of LF only. I recommend to use the following regex to be safe in both cases:

```
$a -replace "\]`r?`n\[", ","
```

Comment: thanks @stackprotector, it's somehow not a newline.

Answer (score 0):

it's somehow not a newline between "]" and "[", there has to be a better way of doing this, but the following is working.

first i replaced the "[]" with a place holder "XXXX", then remove "]" and "[", and finally replace "XXXX" back with "[]"...

```
$a -replace "\[]", "XXXX" -replace "\[", "" -replace "\]", "" -replace "`n"," " -replace "`r"," " -replace "\Z", "," -replace "XXXX", "[]"
```